# exclude match based on node list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

First question on here so bear with me...

**I'm confined to XSLT 1.0 via our CMS :-/**

Trying to create a SiteMap parsing XML with XSL.  But, I need to exclude several directories from being displayed and really don't want to clutter the syntax with a long piped| test statement....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

**<!-- HAVE ALSO TRIED THIS AS A PARAM -->**
<xsl:variable name="pPaths">
    <n>/docs</n>
    <n>/files</n>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="not( starts-with(path, $pPaths) )">  
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.domain.com<xsl:value-of select="path"/></loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
</xsl:if>
```

In the code above, if there is only 1 'n' element it excludes properly.  However, adding the 2nd 'n' stops it from working entirely.

I've also tried these other variations with **no luck**:

```
test="not( starts-with(path, $pPaths/*) )"
test="not( starts-with(path, exsl:node-list($pPaths)) )"
test="not( starts-with(path, exsl:node-list($pPaths/*)) )"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<xsl:if test="not(exsl:node-set($pPaths)/*[starts-with(current()/path, .)])">
```

- `$pPaths` is a variable containing a result tree fragment with two child element nodes.
- `exsl:node-set($pPaths)` is a node set containing one node (the document fragment) which has two child elements.
- `exsl:node-set($pPaths)/*` is a node set containing two nodes (these two child elements).
- `exsl:node-set($pPaths)/*[starts-with(current()/path, .)]` is a node set that will contain zero, one or two nodes (those `n` elements whose text content is a prefix of the current element's first `path` child)
- and finally, `not(...)` is true if that node set is empty, i.e. the current `path` does not match any of the prefixes.

Note that the `/*` goes *outside* the `exsl:node-set(...)` because you need to first convert the RTF to a node set and only then extract its children - you can't navigate from an RTF directly in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  Minor syntax error but it fixed my issue!

    <xsl:if test="not(exsl:node-set($pPaths)/*[starts-with(current()/path, .)])">